# How to create Live Wallpaper in Android?

Tags: android, live, wallpaper

Can someone guide me how to create a live wallpaper in Android. And also, is there a process to use the photos within the gif and implement them into a live wallpaper?  Because that's exactly what I am looking for

Comment: This link may helps too http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/creating-live-wallpapers-on-android/

Comment: AndEngine is not only way to create livewallpaper.Actually most of all andEngine projects' drain phone battery... Also you can search how to create live wallpaper with normal coding. (I mean just android coding,with doesnt using any extra library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to explore more, and use a template for it. You should check andEngine template for creating livewallpaper,
http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/live-wallpaper-template-t258.html

Comment: what does actually template do?

Comment: Makes your life easier in creating live wallpaper.

Comment: I'm waiting for someone to post a youtube video on AndEngine cause getting AndEngine running is a pain in the butt.  Check out this tutorial: http://androidwizard.net/2010/07/live-wallpaper/